Is it possible to turn a utility type into a literal type?
I'm just playing around with TypeScript and wrote this:
// Copied from https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/utils/index.d.ts

type Expect<T extends true> = T
type ExpectFalse<T extends false> = T
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

// own code starts here:

type HTTPChars = 'a' | 'b'
type IsHTTPHost<S extends any, T = S> = S extends HTTPChars
  ? T
  : S extends `${HTTPChars}${infer U}`
    ? IsHTTPHost<U, T>
    : T extends string
      ? `"${T}" contains illegal characters`
      : `Provided value must be a string`;

const hostname1 = 'aaa'
const hostname2 = 'bbb'
const hostname3 = 'something invalid here'
const hostname4 = 9
type cases = [
  Expect<Equal<typeof hostname1, IsHTTPHost<typeof hostname1>>>,
  Expect<Equal<typeof hostname2, IsHTTPHost<typeof hostname2>>>,
  ExpectFalse<Equal<typeof hostname3, IsHTTPHost<typeof hostname3>>>,
  Expect<Equal<IsHTTPHost<typeof hostname3>, '"something invalid here" contains illegal characters'>>,
  Expect<Equal<IsHTTPHost<typeof hostname4>, 'Provided value must be a string'>>
]


Is there any way to derive a type called HTTPHost based on IsHTTPHost above, which
becomes the string literal type limited to all sequences of a and b?

• Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] without external or private dependencies; Expect and Equal are not part of TS. • There is no literal type in TypeScript corresponding to "a string containing only "a" and "b" characters". Only generic types, sort of like your IsHTTPHost (but that's not exactly how I'd write it). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I am missing a type I can use like this: const hostname: HTTPHost = 'ababa' // ok and const hostname: HTTPHost = 'invalid' // not ok.

Sorry, that is impossible as I mentioned. Please re-read my previous comment, [edit] to make your example to be a [mre] without external dependencies, and tell me if I am missing anything about your question.
